# Why is the size of my string changing? (C)

Tags: c, string, string-length, c-strings

```
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
        int i; char c;
        i = 0;
        for (c = getc(fp); c != EOF; c = getc(fp)) {
            c = tolower(c);
            file_string[i] = c;
            i++;
        }
```

In this code, I read through each character of a file, convert it to lower case, and put it in a string.  Now, say I allocate 21 bytes * sizeof(char) to file_string.  Occasionally, after this piece of code shown here, strlen(file_string) will return 30, rather than the expected 20.  Perhaps there is something wrong with my pointer arithmetic?  Some things I have gathered:

1 - This only occurs some of the time.

2 - I have ensured that I am allocating the right amount of bytes to file_string (which happens the line directly before this code).  The code is as follows:

```
fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
file_len = ftell(fp);
file_string = malloc( sizeof(char) * (file_len+1) );
```

printing file_len outputs  the expected length.

3 - I printed out the value of i to make sure it was iterating the exact number of times as the length of file_string, and it is.

4 - Now, DIRECTLY after this code (after closing the file), when I print out the length of file_string, sometimes it will suddenly increase to some larger size.  This has been causing me problems elsewhere in my code.

Now, I figure I can just stick the null terminal character in there and fix the problem (maybe that will cause errors further down the line), but I would prefer to know what's going on under the hood here.

Here is an example of my debugging, showing the change in size before and after.  Bear in mind, the before length corresponds to the file_len variable.

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> file_len: 24
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>i: 0
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>i: 1
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>i: 2
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>i: 3
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>i: 4
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>i: 5
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>i: 6
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>i: 7
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>i: 8
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>i: 9
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>i: 10
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>i: 11
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>i: 12
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>i: 13
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>i: 14
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>i: 15
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>i: 16
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>i: 17
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>i: 18
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>i: 19
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>i: 20
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>i: 21
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>i: 22
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>i: 23
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> strlen(file_string): 30
```

Comment: Three things: (1) there's nothing in the code shown to stop the buffer overflow, (2) you don't create a string because you don't null terminate the string (and you must ensure that you null terminate strings; C won't do it for you — if you want to be nannied, go learn Java or somethng), and (3) `getc()` returns an `int`, not a `char`, because it can return any valid `char` value plus one distinct value, EOF.  Use `int c;` instead of `char c;`.  The standard loop idiom would be `while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now, I figure I can just stick the null terminal character in there and fix the problem (maybe that will cause errors further down the line), but I would prefer to know what's going on under the hood here.

That's literally the solution. `strlen` is searching for a `NULL` terminator in the buffer, but not finding one because you have never added one. After your read code, you should explicitly add the NULL terminator (i.e. `file_string[i] = '\0'`).

Remember that the storage returned by `malloc` is not zeroed, it's basically random data (well...the contents of the storage returned by `malloc` is undefined). What's happening is that you are running off the end of the buffer and into random memory, it just then happens to run into a zero byte further down the line and assumes that is the end of the string.

Comment: Might want to substitute buffer whenever you are not *really* talking about a string.

Comment: @Deduplicator - good point. Is buffer really the right term though? I want to say that it searches for a null terminator somewhere after the given pointer, but that feels too complicated.

Comment: Yes, buffer does not say what it contains. If you want to be more specific but still correct, things get difficult.

Comment: Haha oops, that makes sense that I still need to add a null terminator char.  I was afraid that something else was going on with the memory.  Thank you.

Comment: @Deduplicator - yeah, fair enough. I'll keep it as it is now :)